# Solving a question related to (Independent Events) - Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

One container holds 2 red cubes and 4 blue cubes and a second container holds 4 red cubes and 3 blue cubes. One cube is selected at random from each of the two containers. What is the probability that one of the cubes is red?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I draw a tree diagram to find the probability that one of the cubes is red and I got the answer wrong. Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you looking for the probability that EXACTLY one cube is red, or AT LEAST one cube is red? The answers will be different.

Comment: My understanding of the question is I think that they need (At least one cube is red?). The answer is 11/21. But I don't know how he got this answer.

Comment: 11/21 does not appear to be the correct answer for "at least one cube red". That probability is 5/7. You might be seeking "exactly one cube red" 11/21 is the answer for exactly one cube red, so that's got to be it

Comment: Please show your work in the original post, not in comments.

Comment: Thank you Barrycarter For helping me with this Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is:

1. First Container:

   - 2 Red Cubes
   - 4 Blue Cubes
2. Second container:

   - 4 Red Cubes
   - 3 blue Cubes

There are 4 outcomes and they are as followed:
(R,R), (R,B), (B,R) And (B,B)

The question is asking about the probability of one cube is red out of the 2 containers.

So, the probability will be: 
2/6*3/7+4/6*4/7 
= 11/21